# How to handle http callout response to create records in Flow Builder?

Tags: visual-workflow, httpresponse

I created a flow with an http callout action which is working fine to get data from my external system as I am receiving data as a reponse. It looks like this:

Flow

[image]

But now, I want to create salesforce records using this output. Could you please guide me through the steps to achieve this?

Do I need to use Apex-defined variable(s) for that?

I tried to to so and when defining it, I have to map it with an Apex class. But the list of Apex class available is rather long and I don't know which one to choose nor what to do next...

[image: Apex-defined variable -> Mapping with Apex class]

If someone could at least confirm I am on the right path.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would first need to transform the output you received or indeed, store it in variables. >> To transform the data between Salesforce and the external system in the flow, use the Transform element. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout_configure.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_logic_transform.htm&type=5